# After upgrading with Log4J 2.17.0 unable to populate ThreadContext object

Tags: log4j

**After upgrading with Log4J 2.17.0 unable to populate the ThreadContext object.**

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/

Replaced ThreadContextMap object ${ctx.loginid} with %X{loginid} in pattern layout.

Log printing %X{loginid} instead of printing the login id value.

Any answer would be appreciated?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: May be these will help? https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/wiki/Spring-Cloud-Sleuth-3.0-Migration-Guide#x-b3--mdc-fields-names-are-no-longer-set.      https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/3.0.3/reference/html/project-features.html#features-log-integration